# How to display data in textviews using firebase/android-studio?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of data on firebase real-time database and i would like to display this data in textview at my android studio user activity. what should i do to dispaly the currently logged user data?

my database:

[image: my database]

this is my user profile activity:

[image: this is my user profile activity]

Comment: There are some pretty good tutorials on Firebase out there. Did you try anything yet? If not, I recommend the [Firebase codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). A few hours spent there will answer most of the basic questions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding event listener to your firebase ref. Sorry i couldnt see your images so ill just give you an example

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
threadRef = database.getReference("Thread")
threadRef.orderByChild("time").addValueEventListener(threadListener);

ValueEventListener threadListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageThread : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String time = (String) messageThread.child("time").getValue();
            mTextViewer.setText(time);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {}
};
```